# Why does project management tool don't have restrictions in their projects?

Tags: pm-software

I'm currently developing a **project management software** for my thesis project and I have researched some of the established project management tools for reference of this said project.

But I just don't know why do other project management tools like [Basecamp](http://basecamp.com) and [Producteev](http://producteev.com) don't have restrictions in their project, in terms of creating tasks, deleting tasks and assigning tasks that anyone could create task edit task and delete tasks?

I need some advice, hope you guys can help. Thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: Is this question only about the tools mentioned in it (Basecamp and Producteev) or it is general about any Project Management tool?

Comment: @Dhiman what I mean there is all project management tool which don't have restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - because everyone on the project are professionals.

Long answer - Some times tools need restrictions, either for security, or to protect users from themselves.  Restrictions have a cost though, you need to have defined user groups with different permissions, you need rules as to who has access to what, and so on.  The problem with this is that this causes unnecessary complexity for projects where it isn't needed. I'm not saying it's never needed, but it often isn't. This is why you see the openness of those tools.

This isn't an agile question per se, but I'm going to beat on that drum for a bit.  The first 'rule' in the agile manifesto is **individuals and interactions over process and tools**.  Allowing everyone access to everything allows everyone to see the big picture.  Also, you won't need the additional overhead of a "tool admin", and if the PM/admin gets hit by a proverbial bus, other team members can still use the tool.